# Two instances of BusyBox on separate Serial lines (ttySn)

Tags: console, embedded-linux, busybox

I am working on an arm board which has two serial ports, accessible through /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyS1.

Busybox runs on /dev/ttyS0. 
I am able to write data on /dev/ttyS1 using 'echo' command like so

```
#echo "microMolvi" > /dev/ttyS1
```

I was wondering if there is a way to run another instance of busybox(shell) on /dev/ttyS1, so that I may be able to work with two virtual terminals simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out that the first shell, that runs on ttyS0, was configured to behave so in the /etc/inittab file.

This line in /etc/inittab was responsible for invocation of the default shell at ttyS0:

```
ttyS0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 38400 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

So, based on my gut feeling, I put a getty on the second serial port by adding the following line in /etc/inittab

```
ttyS1::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS1 38400 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

It worked like a charm.
Hope this helps someone someday.

Comment: Note: you can get the correct speed `38400` from `console=` cmdline parameter (defined in bootloader or in Linux in `/proc/cmdline`).